# Bitrise x Danger : bundle install, Could not locate Gemfile in "Do anything with Script step"

Tags: github, continuous-integration, bitrise

I'm new to CI, bitrise.

I've connected bitrise, project and Github and succeeded vanilla build.

Now I'm trying to show Auto PR comments on Github by using Danger connecting bitrise.
However, after pushing commits and making a pull request, the build was failed with this error on "Do anything with Script step" phase on bitrise.

[image]

What does "Could not locate Gemfile" mean in this case?
I have already added gemfile in local by these commands,

```
// create gemfile on the project directory
$ bundler init

// add danger in gemfile
gem "danger"

// install
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec danger init
```

And I've done

- adding DANGER_GITHUB_API_TOKEN and github Access token in Env vars in bitrise
- adding scripts in Do anything with Script step

This is my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# fail if any commands fails
set -e
# debug log
set -x

# these 2 lines are what I added
bundle install
bundle exec danger

# write your script here
echo "Hello World!"

# or run a script from your repository, like:
# bash ./path/to/script.sh
# not just bash, e.g.:
# ruby ./path/to/script.rb
```

Is something missing to make Danger work in Github?

I have no idea what's going on here and I don't know even where I need to check.
If you have any ideas, please help me.
Feel free to ask me if you need more info to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me because I was executing the Danger script before the Git Clone Repository step in my workflow.. It can't find the Gemfile because it's not in the correct directory; `$BITRISE_SOURCE_DIR` is not set prior to the Git Clone Repository step.